# Error invalid json primitive after file is validated

Tags: c#, json

I try to deserialize my json using javascriptserializer, but get the error "Invalid json primitive"

Other post mentioned to validate the json, which I did.

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic jsonObject = sr.DeserializeObject(@"TableReloadStatus.json");
jsonObject.SchemaName = "Test";
var modifiedJsonString = sr.Serialize(jsonObject);
```

My json:

```
[{
    "Tables":[
    {
        "ServerName": "win-3hog2kbe0g2",
        "TaskName": "tskMovieDemoUAT2",
        "SchemaName": "MOVIEDEMO",
        "TableName": "MOVIE_FACT_HDFS_EXT_TAB",
        "DateReload": "01/25/2019"
    },
    {
        "ServerName": "win-3hog2kbe0g2",
        "TaskName": "tskMovieDemoUAT",
        "SchemaName": "MOVIEDEMO",
        "TableName": "MOVIE_FACT_HDFS_EXT_TAB",
        "DateReload": "01/24/2019"
    }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a JSON array contain `Tables` another JSON array is not an object, so you might try to use this.

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic jsonObject = sr.DeserializeObject(@"TableReloadStatus.json");
jsonObject[0].Tables[0].SchemaName = "Test";
```

I recommend [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) libary.

I would use a class model to carry that JSON, instead of using `dynamic`

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`

```
public class Table
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string DateReload { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

then use would be like.

```
string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"TableReloadStatus.json");
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonData);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQbqim)